# Disqus-like comment server

Tags: blog, server, webserver, comments

I'm looking at setting up a blog, and I think I want to go the static website compiler route, rather than the perhaps more conventional Wordpress route. I'm looking at using [blogofile](http://www.blogofile.com/), but could use [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) as well.

These tools recommend using [disqus](http://disqus.com/) to embed a javascript comment widget on blog posts. I'd go that route, but I'd rather host the comments myself, rather than use a third party. I could certainly write my own dirt-simple comment server, but I was wondering if anyone knew of one that already exists (of the open source variety).

Thanks!

Comment: Disqus has a feature list ranging from realtime updates and media embedding to community profiles and fetching of external(eg. Twitter) reactions. Maybe you could be a little more specific what of all that you're *actually* looking for, because it's somewhat doubtful you're going to find all of it in one package.

Answer (score 2):

[Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) has a [comment module](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/comments/) built in, and there are also [many third-party comment modules](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/commenting/).